# MySQL changing collation deleted data

Tags: php, mysql

I changed my collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8mb4_bin` to try and show emojis and em dashes, but it deleted all the data in one entry after the em dash. I've changed the collation back but it hasn't returned.

My questions are:

1. How can I recover the data?
2. How can I display emojis and em dashes?

I am storing data in a MySQL database and accessing it with PHP using this code:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch(); 
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT entry, date FROM entries WHERE user_id=? ORDER BY date DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($entry, $date);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $date = date("j M", strtotime($date));
        echo "<div class='entry'><div class='date'>$date</div><div class='entry-text'>$entry</div></div>";
}
```

Comment: what is your connection charset and your column collation?

Comment: "_How can I recover the data?_" Did you have a backup? If not, you probably aren't going to be able to recover the data.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz my default character set is `latin1`, default collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`. Not sure why Swedish, given I'm not in Sweden.

Comment: @Sebastian : **1**. change collation its not delete data, but convert your data only (weird char may appear or (?), but not deleted) **2**. if your old data was truely deleted, you cannot recover them if you dont have backup. **3**. to show emoji is easy, make sure your db connection is utf8mb4 and the column collation is one of utf8mb4 collation, recommend: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` **4**. `latin1_swedish_ci` is  mysql default collation. all of us have that not only sweden

Comment: @plonknimbuzz when I change that, everything after an apostrophe in a field disappears

Comment: may we discuss this on chat?
 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163897/utf8mb4

Comment: @Sebastian sorry , im losing connection 2 hours ago until now. i need revision my last chat: you will destroy/lose your data if you change the collation directly. Thats why phpmyadmin show alert when you change the collation. So carefully of this. and 1 more. your phpmyadmin is using latin1 as charset connection by default. this will cuase you cant insert emoji directly from phpmyadmin because the connection charset is latin1 not utf8mb4. So if you want direct insert emoji just change phpmyadmin connection charset to utf8mb4.